# How to run arbitrary JavaScript remotely (from file or as js expression) for an already open browser tab?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there any way to run JavaScript for any already open browser tab remotely? For example if there is a tab open (of some web page which I don't control) and I want to run a script within the context of that tab, e.g by piping a script to it from the shell somehow.

The idea is to develop the script from the comfort of any other IDE and run the result in context of a pre-existing web page.

Preferably, each run would be run in isolation such that multiple evaluations of `const someVar = 1` wouldn't conflict (as a `const` can't be redefined).

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "use browser's developer console remotely?" Are you asking how to access the developer tools for a browser running on remote Machine A from local Machine B?

Comment: If you want to write code that's run on a domain you don't control, you probably just need to write a browser add-on. If you want 2 runs of `const someVar = 1;` to not conflict, give each statement its own scope.

Comment: @smallpepperz I've clarified the question, is it more understandable now?

Comment: "*develop the script from the comfort of my preferred editor and run it in the browser to test.*" - it sounds what you are looking for is hot (module) reloading of a web page/application you are developing. This is a pretty standard feature of modern dev environments.

Comment: @Bergi I've clarified the question even more. The thing is: I'd like to run some random script for an external web site (which I'm not developing myself), but create/run the script from my editor instead of needing to copy-paste it to the developer tools console. I've also actually found the answer, see my answer below :).

Answer (score 0):

For Chromium based browsers, one can run JavaScript remotely in debugger mode:

1. Run browser: `chromium --remote-debugging-port=9222`
2. List open tabs: `curl -s -o - http://127.0.0.1:9222/json`
3. Send script to page using [`Runtime.evaluate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-evaluate):

   ```bash
   page_id=9EB553A6AE7860E5036BCE836258E22F # sample id from step 2
   code='(function() { console.log("Hello, console!"); return 42; })()'
   jq -c -n \
     --arg code "$code" \
     '{id: 0, method: "Runtime.evaluate", "params":{expression: $code}}' \
        | websocat -t - "ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/$page_id"
   ```

In the last step, the important thing is to send a correctly escaped JavaScript as string in JSON object, I'm using `jq` and `websocat` to achieve that, but other tools will do as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of ways to control computers remotely, such as through SSH, VNC, TeamViewer, NoMachine, etc.  All of those, except SSH, allow graphical control, so you can click/type into a browser remotely with them.

If instead you want to allow users to expose their computer to you, you could always write a browser plug-in, and it could make `fetch` requests to your server to get code.  However, browser plug-ins do have some security restrictions that may limit you, depending on what exactly you want to accomplish.

In particular, there are limits to what a plug-in can do with the dev console.  I know some manipulation is possible, as there are plug-ins like the React Developer Tools which interact with the browser dev tools ... but you'd have to research more to see exactly what the limits are.  Likewise, there are also limits to what plug-ins can do to the filesystem, but I believe [plug-ins can affect it](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/reference/fileSystem) (with user permission).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but when using a graphical interface I'd still be going through an open developer console. I was more aiming at piping a .js file into the browser somehow from shell (for an already open browser tab).

Comment: Again, with a browser extension you don't even need an open tab: the extension can fetch the JS and pipe it directly into the page. I don't believe there is an easy way to pipe scripts in from the command line; you'd have to use the debugger as @Cigarette Smoking Man suggests.

Comment: But *I want* to access data from the open tab -- that is a precondition to this entire question. Secondly, the remote debugger is rather easy to use (i.e just run Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9222
`) than creating a new browser extension.